# equivalent to Content Provider in Windows Store App

Tags: android, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

[Android Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) system allows other apps to access the data of an app.
Is there any equivalent, or similar approach in WinRT?

I read [App contract and extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464906.aspx) and [Share contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758314.aspx) in MSDN, but it has to execute provider app (an app holds data source) firstly, and then select target app afterward.

In Android Content Provider however, it can query data provider's repository while using target app (data receiver) with no selection of choosing steps. small but big difference in usage.

Comment: The usage difference is one of the features of Windows 8 in that it helps prevent user data from leaking. I believe one app can share data without having to be directly accessed. Consider how the People app shares Contacts without being opened directly. That is likely a special case, but there may be something similar to it, such as with the FilePicker.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of data you want your app to share, but it seems to me that what you are looking for might be the [file picker contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465192.aspx). They, I quote:

> Make files accessible from a file picker if your app has a unique and/or valuable view of those files or if users cannot easily access the files another way.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to give "queryable dataset" to other apps. a data can be a usage data of my app, for example. If File Picker is the only choice, I have to order user to store a file to My Document directory or somewhere, and pick it from other app. lots of process...